# What's the difference between the "%s" in vim normal mode and regular GNU sed

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, vim

I am quite new to regex, and thought markdown(custom/madeup format of maardown) to html conversion using regex would be a good way to get started. When I'm within Vim(8.1), say converting this line;

```
+style
#include <style.css>
-style
```

to;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

I used this command in Vim;

```
:%s/^+style$\n\(.*\)$\n^-style/<link rel="stylesheet" type="text\/css" href="\1">/g
```

And I get exactly what I was hopping for. However, when I ran the same command from my terminal using GNU sed, I get no change in output;

```
sed 's/^+style$\n\(.*\)$\n^-style/<link rel="stylesheet" type="text\/css" href="\1">/g'
```

Also, including the `-z` flag doen't seem to be much of a help either, the output remains same as input.

I wonder why that is.

Comment: Vim will happily match across lines, `sed` doesn't (and GNU sed's `-z` is essentially redefining what a line is)

Comment: `$` is the end of the line, and you just redefined what a line is with `-z`, so you have to account for that in your pattern now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` command, as it stands in the question, would not be able to see any newline characters in its input at all since `sed` is a line-oriented editor. The data will be presented to `sed` one line at a time, with the actual newline characters removed.

Adding `-z` with GNU `sed` would make the utility use nul (`\0`) as its  delimiter.  This means you now would get the *whole* document at once into the `sed` editing buffer, and be able to match newlines using `\n`. However, it also means `^` and `$` would not match the start and end of *lines* any longer.

Personally, I would use the standard `sed` command

```bsh
sed '/^+style$/,/^-style$/ s|^#include.*|<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">|' file
```

This does three things differently from what you are trying to do:

1. It uses an address range, `/^+style$/,/^-style$/`, addressing the lines that the `s///` command should affect.
2. Within the range, the substitution command  matches `#include` at the start of the line.
3. The substitution command is written with `|` as delimiter instead of the usual `/` to allow the pattern and/or replacement text to contain `/` without escaping it.  This helps readability.

(It furthermore does not *require* GNU `sed`.)

The modified command would also work in Vim, although you would have to use `/` as the delimiters for the `s///` command there. The `ed` editor would be able to use the same command as `sed` though.

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!